# Can the Android version be updated on Genymotion emulators?

Tags: android, genymotion

I am trying to reproduce an issue that occurs when Android is upgraded from Nougat to Oreo. I am unable to trigger an operating system upgrade on a Genymotion emulator. Is even possible? Could not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible, and unlikely to become possible in the future (though one should never say never)